# Access docker container by FQDN

Tags: proxy, docker, reverse-proxy

I have several docker containers running web apps. They can be accessed on my network using the IP of the host and the port number i've bound to in the container.

I would like to be able to access the apps via a fqdn, for example, app1.home.com (or home.com/app1 if that is easier).

To achieve this I guess I would need a dhcp and dns server running on my network. I plan to configure dnsmasq. This would allow me to resolve the home.com domain locally.

Then I figure I would need a proxy of some description to route to the specific port. I know this can be achieved with nginx or apache, but I don't know how and it seems a bit over kill. I think HAProxy could be an option, again I dont know how.

TL;DR: How can I address web-apps running in docker containers using a fqdn on my home network?

Answer (score 0):

Just configure your docker host to have several ips, one for each hostname you would like to configure. Then configure dnsmasq to point each ip to a different hostname, site1.home.com->X.X.X.X, site2.home.com->Y.Y.Y.Y. All of these ips will belong to your docker host.

Then start up your containers on the docker host. I use docker swarm with an overlay network, frontended by an nginx reverse proxy. I set up docker containers to belong to this overlay network, and I specify --names for them so the docker overlay network has it's own dns for the nginx reverse proxy to use to point to other containers.

Then I configure nginx to point to the other containers using swarm-based dns depending on the ip used to connect to the docker host. So http://X.X.X.X/ is translated by nginx to point to dns name site1 on the overlay network. nginx will go get the site1 container's webpage and return it to the user. It is a lot of overkill but has huge advantages are that it does this redundantly with little downtime because of rolling updates.

For example: I go to home1.home.com in my browser. This triggers a dns lookup changing home1.home.com to X.X.X.X. I am directed to the docker host's nginx reverse proxy, which gets site1's webpage that is hosted on the internal overlay network, based on the ip I used to connect to the docker host. It then presents the webpage to me.